# Update specific document without the ID in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to update a document without knowing the specific ID of this document.

My document on firebase:

[image: My document on firebase]

I searched on the internet and find this ([update cloud firestore document without id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541228/update-cloud-firestore-document-without-id)) ;

```
const db = Firebase.firestore()
    db.collection('users').where("email", "==", currentUser.email).get(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(document){
            document.ref.update({
                "firstname" : "world",
                "name" : "testing"
            })
        });
    })
```

it doesn't show me an error and doesn't change anything in firestore.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const db = Firebase.firestore()
    db.collection('users').where("email", "==", currentUser.email).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>  
            "firstname" : "world",
            "name" : "testing"
        }))
    })
}
```

and this show me an error ; doc.update is not a function and I don't really understand why. If anyone can enlighten me!

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you await for the first get function  to complete, then update the results returned, if any?

Comment: Have a look at the answer you copied from again. I turns out I had a mistake in there, which could explain why it didn't work for you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I try to find the mistake but I don't get it.. Can you explain me ? thanks

Comment: In your first snippet `.get(function(querySnapshot){` should be `.get().then(function(querySnapshot){`

Comment: it's working! I'm new with React so I'm still trying to figure some things out.. Thank you for your help! @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working!    I closed this question as a duplicate of the original you linked, since I fixed the problem that was in my answer there,